# How to print the string using foreach using with addition function? in perl

Tags: perl

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @a = qw(1 2 3 4 'c');
my @b = qw(5 6 7 8);
my $i; 
for ($i=0; $i < scalar @a; $i++)
{
    my $ax = $a[$i] + $b[$i];
    print "$ax\n";
 }
```

How to print the string variable `c` when using the `add` function.

```
# I expect output
6
8
10 
12
c
```

Comment: What do you actually get?

Comment: What do you expect of `'c' + undef` to be?

Comment: How to print 'c' in foreach add function.

Comment: Are you trying to use hexadecimal?

Comment: The real question is why one would hold strings in array together with numbers, which can lead to XY question.

Answer (score 2):

In other languages, e.g., Javascript and, somewhat, in Python, `+` does both numeric addition and string concatenation.

But not in Perl.

In Perl, string concatenation is done with `.` and numeric addition with `+`

That is why this  script produces the "isn't numeric in addition" warning.

The "use of uninitialized value" warning comes from going beyond the end of the @b array.

These are warnings. Execution did not stop.  Note that the script decided that "c" was equivalent to 0 and undefined was equivalent to 0, and produced 0 as the addition on the last line.

```
6
8
10
12
Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at test.pl line 8.
Argument "'c'" isn't numeric in addition (+) at test.pl line 8.
0
```

It is possible to overload '+' within a custom class, and it would be possible to write a custom class that adds scalars that match a numeric regex with + and concats others.  But modifying core functionality would be unusual.  In any event, these techniques are beyond the scope of this answer.